# SQL multiple insert procedure

Tags: sql, insert, mariadb, procedure

I've been stuck all morning and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is here, could a kind soul help me out:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE value(
    IN group1 CHAR(20), 
    IN ns1 CHAR(20), 
    IN title1 CHAR(20))   
BEGIN
  insert into translationmarker 
      (site, `group`, ns, title, `type`) 
      values 
      (`cms`, group1, ns1, title1, `value`)
  insert into translation 
      (marker, locale, `value`) 
      select id, 'en', 'test' 
      from translationmarker 
      where `group` = group1 and ns = ns1 and title = title1
  insert into translationjavascript 
      select id 
      from translationmarker 
      where `group` = group1 and ns = ns1 and title = title1
END
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into translation 
      (marker, locale, `value`) 
      selec' at line 10
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing semi-colons (at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using backticks, where you intend single quotes.  In addition, you need to make sure you have a `delimiter` statement.  Perhaps this will work:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE translationvalue(
    IN in_group1 CHAR(20), 
    IN in_ns1 CHAR(20), 
    IN in_title1 CHAR(20)
)   
BEGIN
  insert into vitanet__translationmarker(site, `group`, ns, title, `type`) 
      values ('cms', in_group1, in_ns1, in_title1, 'value');

  insert into vitanet__translation (marker, locale, `value`) 
      select id, 'en', 'test' 
      from vitanet__translationmarker 
      where `group` = in_group1 and ns = in_ns1 and title = in_title1;

  insert into vitanet__translationjavascript(id)
      select id 
      from vitanet__translationmarker 
      where `group` = in_group1 and ns = in_ns1 and title = in_title1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Notes:

- I changed the parameter names to have an `in_` prefix.  This helps distinguish them from columns in tables.
- In the first `values()` statement, I replaced backticks with single quotes.
- I added the `delimiter` statements and semicolons to the end of lines.
- Naming a column `group` is a really bad idea, because that is a SQL keyword and a MySQL reserved word.
- I added the `id` column explicitly to the last `insert`.  Even if there is one column, I think it is still best practice to include the name of the column (I am guessing it is called `id`).

Comment: Thank you, you are a lifesaver! I know that naming a column 'group' is a bad idea. The problem being this project was started by other people long time ago so there are some things like that in it from those times.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the query terminator `;` after the each `INSERT` block.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE translationvalue(
    IN group1 CHAR(20), 
    IN ns1 CHAR(20), 
    IN title1 CHAR(20))   
BEGIN
  insert into vitanet__translationmarker 
      (site, `group`, ns, title, `type`) 
      values 
      (`cms`, group1, ns1, title1, `value`);

  insert into vitanet__translation 
      (marker, locale, `value`) 
      select id, 'en', 'test' 
      from vitanet__translationmarker 
      where `group` = group1 and ns = ns1 and title = title1;

  insert into vitanet__translationjavascript 
      select id 
      from vitanet__translationmarker 
      where `group` = group1 and ns = ns1 and title = title1;

END
```